# Dryscrape visit works only once in python

Tags: python, dryscrape

I want visit page in loop.

Code is:

```
import dryscrape

dryscrape.start_xvfb()
sess = dryscrape.Session()
url = 'http://192.168.1.5';
loop = 1
while loop < 100000: 

    sess.set_header('user-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.4; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2225.0 Safari/537.36')
    sess.set_attribute('auto_load_images', False)
    sess.set_timeout(30)
    sess.visit(url)
    response = sess.body()
    print(response)
    print('loop:', loop)
    sess.reset()
    loop = loop + 1
```

According to output, page is visited only once time, I don't understand why? In 2., 3., .... there is no output:

```
('loop:', 1)
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Javascript scraping test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="intro-text">Yay! Supports javascript</p>
  <script>
     document.getElementById('intro-text').innerHTML = 'Yay! Supports javascript';
  </script> 

</body></html>
('loop:', 2)

('loop:', 3)

('loop:', 4)

('loop:', 5)

('loop:', 6)

('loop:', 7)
```

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like dryscrape is smart enough to skip urls it has already visited.

Comment: @JohnGordon Is there any method for clean history, or somethink like this?

Comment: What exactly you want to see the output? it seems like you are setting session with a URL and dryscrape scrapes a URL only once in a session. If you want to scrape the same URL again, you will have to set session again.

Comment: @Sheshnath I need the javascript enabled output each time.

Comment: @RajanChauhan: have you tested your code with a different server? I have tested successfully with http://www.google.com and [http://httpbin.org/ip](http://httpbin.org/ip)  and get a response for every request.

Comment: @mhawke Try it on https://www.screener.in/company/TCS/ I am not getting similiar output after 1st loop

Comment: @RajanChauhan: screener.in/company/TCS also works for me. What version of Python, dryscrape, webkit_server, xvfbwrapper are you using? Which OS? What are the version of the dependencies qtwebkit and qtwebkit-devel - qt4 or qt5? Are you using a proxy server?

Comment: i am using qt4  and ubuntu. Not on a proxyserver though. 
webkit-server==1.0
xvfbwrapper==0.2.9
dryscrape==1.0

Comment: @RajanChauhan: unfortunately I have not been able to replicate your problem. I've tried qt4 (libqtwebkit-dev) on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, dryscrape (1.0), webkit-server. xvfbwrapper (0.2.9), lxml (4.1.0), Python 3.5. It works as expected.

Comment: Try printing the status code after each visit: `print(sess.status_code())`

Comment: @RajanChauhan, you are using dryscrape which on their git repo says it is no longer maintained. I would suggest you use something which is more latest in nature. Scrapy+Splash or Selenium+ChromeHeadless or https://github.com/iiSeymour/chromote. There are lot of other options that you can try

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with me i solve this with def try this

```
def fb(user,pwd)
 import dryscrape as d
 d.start_xvfb()
 Br = d.Session()
 #every time it creat a new session
 Br.visit('http://fb.com')
 Br.at_xpath('//*[@name = "email"]').set(user)
 Br.at_xpath('//*[@name = "pass"]').set(pwd)
 Br.at_xpath('//*[@name = "login"]').click()
 #......Now Do Something you want.....#
```

Then after making def now use this

```
 fb('my@account.com','password')
```

Then automatic login yourself user this command 100 time without error

Please read and answers my Question [Same name links cant click python dryscrape](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47430217/8282490)

Answer (score -1):

After updating dryscrape and its dependencies to the latest version, it works fine now.

The versions are:
dryscrape-1.0, lxml-4.1.1, webkit-server-1.0, xvfbwrapper-0.2.9

The code:

```
import dryscrape
dryscrape.start_xvfb()
sess = dryscrape.Session()
url = 'http://192.168.1.5/jsSupport.html';
loop = 1
while loop < 100000:

    sess.set_header('user-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.4; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2225.0 Safari/537.36')
    sess.set_attribute('auto_load_images', False)
    sess.set_timeout(30)
    sess.visit(url)
    response = sess.body()
    print(response)
    print('loop:', loop)
    sess.reset()
    loop = loop + 1
```

Output:

```
   'loop:' 1
   <!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Javascript scraping test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <p id="intro-text">Yay! Supports javascript</p>
     <script>
        document.getElementById('intro-text').innerHTML = 'Yay! Supports javascript';
     </script> 

   </body></html>
   'loop:' 2
   <!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Javascript scraping test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <p id="intro-text">Yay! Supports javascript</p>
     <script>
        document.getElementById('intro-text').innerHTML = 'Yay! Supports javascript';
     </script> 

   </body></html>
   'loop:' 3
   <!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Javascript scraping test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <p id="intro-text">Yay! Supports javascript</p>
     <script>
        document.getElementById('intro-text').innerHTML = 'Yay! Supports javascript';
     </script> 

   </body></html>
```

If you cant update the modules, or dont want to, a quick fix will be visiting another page at the end of the loop.

```
import dryscrape
dryscrape.start_xvfb()
sess = dryscrape.Session()
url = 'http://192.168.1.5/jsSupport.html';
otherurl = "http://192.168.1.5/test"
loop = 1
while loop < 100000:

    sess.set_header('user-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.4; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2225.0 Safari/537.36')
    sess.set_attribute('auto_load_images', False)
    sess.set_timeout(30)
    sess.visit(url)
    response = sess.body()
    print(response)
    print('loop:', loop)
    sess.reset()
    loop = loop + 1
    sess.visit(otherurl) #Visits the other url, so that when sess.visit(url) is called, it is forced to visit the page again.
```